# Is there any difference between Windows 7 Home Premium and Windows 7 Professional performance-wise?

Tags: windows-7

If I upgrade my PC from Win 7 Home to Win 7 Professional, is there going to be any degradation in performance?

I looked at the comparison chart and there was nothing that says anything about performance.

Answer (score 5):

Basically the upgrade bring different tools, different services. So depending on the configuration you use with the two OSes you can notice performance enhancement or degradation.

But the kernel remains the same.

Comment: +1 for same kernel but different services. The real answer is "it depends" but you've summed it up well.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the system specs for Windows 7 Professional to be of some help: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/business/windows-7-system-requirements.aspx